# What is orientation constants for views?

Tags: android, android-view

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="12dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

What is `android:orientation="horizontal"` in the above xml?

The Android-Studio quick tip shows it is orientation constant, which is not very helpful.

Answer (score 8):

`android:orientation` is only relevant in a `ViewGroup` where its children are organized consecutively such as a `LinearLayout`, so in your case it's absolutely useless.

Comment: It seems weird, that they have made  it attribute of `View`,when they could have easily made it attribute of `ViewGroup`

Answer (score 3):

there is no use for orientation attribute in View, orientation is only required for Linear layout or other parent layouts

Answer (score 2):

Orientation constants are mainly used for View Groups it shows how child of that viewGroup should arrange. As view is a parent class of all ViewGroups

See the screenshot

[image]

Explanation is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#orientation)

Suppose you have any LinearLayout and you want the content inside that Layout to be set in vertical manner then you can use this orientation  constant as vertical and all components inside that LinearLayout in vertical orientation

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello, I am a TextView" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, I am a Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In relative layout it can be achieve as described here,

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

but in **Parent class View this is not useful at all**

Comment: so it is applicable to `ViewGroup` only, then it doesn't make sense to have the attibute in `View`.

Comment: yes Look ViewGroups Extends View class so if you want property to be use in those viewgroups it must be there in view class also, But it seems no prior use in default View class @q126y

Comment: Property is not useful in your case

Comment: `if you want property to be use in those viewgroups it must be there in view class also`  wrong

Comment: Yes its wrong you can also declare it in ViewGroups but as inheritance is a good way to do this for more re usability its good to declare property in View class so that it's more usable for all child classes.

Comment: since it is only used in `ViewGroup` it doesn't make sense to have it in `View`. Are there other `View` subclasses that use this attribute?

Comment: No I don't think so.